# Em Python temos a função switch?

Tags: python, switch

Em Python temos a função `switch`? queria criar um programa mas não queria usar muitos `if`, e pra isso a função `switch` ajuda, mas já vi varias vídeos aulas de Python e nenhuma fala de `switch`, por acaso não existe em Python?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Não tem, em geral a solução é usar `if` e `elif`:

```
x = 1
if x == 0:
    print("imprime 0")
elif x == 1:
    print("imprime 1")
elif x == 2:
    print("imprime 2")
else:
   print("imprime outra coisa")
```

Ou um dicionário que gera algo próximo, mas não tem opção *default* então teria que verificar antes se encaixa em alguma ou ter certeza que sempre será válido.

```
x = 1
print({
        1 : "deu um",
        2 : "deu dois",
    }[x])
```

Ou se quiser que execute algo:

```
print({
        1 : lambda x: x + 2,
        2 : lambda x: x - 2,
        3 : lambda x: x * 2
}[x](5))
```

Se quiser algo mais complexo aí terá que criar funções e chamar aí.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/L7PXTD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rppuuqhs-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/SwitchLike.py).

`if` e `switch` é essencialmente a mesma coisa. O único ganho real dele é a otimização que algumas linguagens fazem, mas faz pouco sentido em Python. O `switch` pode ter um custo de sintaxe mais alto em alguns casos. Algumas linguagens colocam funcionalidade extra no `switch`.

Eu uso uma linguagem que o `switch` não traz vantagens. Prefiro usar o `if` mesmo.

`switch` não é uma função é um comando de linguagem.

Note que em versões recentes Python passou ter um comando com a palavra chave `switch`, porém ele não é o mecanismo consagrado existente nas outras linguagens. Ele é um *pattern matching* e não uma *jump table* que é o mecanismo concreto do `switch`.

Comment: Muito obrigada, ajudou demais :)

Comment: Só um adendo. Tem diferença sim, ainda que pouca. No switch por exemplo vc pode não dar break e avaliar duas ou mais expressões ao mesmo tempo. Com elif não dá, so fazendo uma sequencia de if sem else, mas ficaira mais lento. Além do mais, internamente switch é mais rápido segundo alguns benchmarks, mas é questionavel.

Comment: @maniero quando vc fala: 'Eu uso uma linguagem que o `switch` não traz vantagens. Prefiro usar o `if ` mesmo. `switch` não é uma função é um comando de linguagem'  Você usa o `if` apenas por preferência, ou existe alguma perda de desempenho ao usar o `switch` ? ( em linguagens que permitam este comando)

Comment: @LuizAugusto Na maioria das linguagens o `switch` é mais rápido e o uso, neste caso que não há ganho a sintaxe é um pouco pior no `switch` então prefiro não usar, mas é coisa bem específica dessa linguagem. O comando nem chama `switch` nela, apenas ele é parecido e existe por questões de legado.